# Accidentally A Riley [first attempt]

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

This is my first time attempting to create a Riley Riddle.

> My head travels constantly at the velocity of the product of setting ablaze.
>   My body is the head of a color, when the wavelength is DXC to 26C nm, they blaze.
>   My suffix, are the occurrence of hitting a surface, when they are rays.
>   What am I? When you get it, I hope you didn't just utter a random phrase.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Smock has already identified parts of it but I think the overall answer is

> Coincidence

My head travels constantly at the velocity of the product of setting ablaze.

> The speed of light in a vaccum is constant and denoted by **c** (already found by Smock)

My body is the head of a color, when the wavelength is DXC to 26C nm, they blaze.

> DXC is 590 in Roman numerals, 26C in hex is 620 in decimal (found by Smock). 590-620nm is roughly the range on the electromagnetic spectrum corresponding to orange, whose head is **o** (also mentioned by Smock)

My suffix, are the occurrence of hitting a surface, when they are rays.

> Incidence - in physics, is the intersection of a line, or something moving in a straight line, such as a beam of light, with a surface.

What am I? When you get it, I hope you didn't just utter a random phrase.

> Is it a coincidence that we obtain the answer?

Title

> Coincidental is synonymous with accidental

Comment: Good job! As it's my first one it might not sound as good. I tried my very best to rhyme.

Answer (score 5):

the head seems like:

> the speed of light, which would be 'c'

The body might be:

> not sure about the DXC but Hex 26C = Decimal 620, which would make it orange - the head of which would be 'o'

Suffix:

> not really sure with this at all - if it's light again then perhaps reflection or refraction ? but that wouldn't make a word with 'co' at the beginning that had anything to do with a random phrase...

Comment: Nice try! Very good indeed!